# Ajax POST request in Flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, flask

I'm trying to receive a POST request containing user-input form data using AJAX, but I keep returning errors. I'm following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IZWtHsM3Y5A) almost verbatim.

Here's my code:

views.py

```
@app.route('/table_data', methods=['POST'])
def table_data():
    user_id = request.form['userID']
    name = request.form['name']
    return user_id, name    #of course I'll return something more meaningful in the future
```

datapage.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="app/static/js/submit.js"></script>
<form action="{{ url_for('table_data') }}" class="form-inline" method="post"
        role="form" enctype="application/json">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="userID" placeholder="4-Character ID">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name">
    <button type='submit' class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
</form>
```

submit.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').on('submit', function(event) {
        $.ajax({
            data: {
                userID: $('#userID').val(),
                name: $('#name').val()
            },
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/table_data'
        })
    event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

My console is returning "GET /app/static/js/submit.js HTTP/1.1" 404", even though I know that the route to submit.js is correct.

I'm brand new to JavaScript/jQuery. Any help for a rookie?

Comment: Try with the url fro the JS as `/static/js/submit.js`

Comment: Okay, now I'm getting "GET /app/static/js/submit.js HTTP/1.1" 200", but also this " "POST /table_data HTTP/1.1" 400 -". And in my localhost window, I get "Bad Request - The browser (or proxy) sent a request that this server could not understand." No idea why.

Comment: 400 is bad request, usually malformed data. Tryo to `console.log()` the data in the browser before the request is sent

Comment: I think you are missing some closing `})`  in you JS code

Comment: @reptilicus I figured it out - needed to add "name" parameters to the input fields that matched the "id" parameters in the HTML script. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @reptilicus yeah you were right about the closing }), but that was just an error in my formatting here. I'll edit the OP to fix it. Thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> **SOLUTION:**
>
> First, thanks to @reptilicus for the solution to the 404 error on the .js file (see comments). After that I was stuck with a "Bad Request" error message (400) in the browser window because my HTML input parameters did not include "name". I added *name="userID"* and *name="name"* to the  tags in the HTML script, and it ran.